# bash regex email

Tags: regex, bash, validation, email, interactive

I am traying to interactively ask in bash for an email address till it gets a valid one. Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
email=""
email_status=[ "$email" =~ ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$ ]
while [ $email_status ]
do
    read -p "Enter admin email: " email
    echo
    if [[ "$email" =~ ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$ ]]
    then
        echo "Email address $email is valid."
    else
        echo "Email address $email is invalid."
    fi
done
```

I don't get why is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is with the part where you seem to be setting up the conditions for the initial condition for the `while` loop.  We can simplify the whole loop by just exiting the loop on the desired condition like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    read -p "Enter admin email: " email
    echo
    if [[ "$email" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ ]]
    then
        echo "Email address $email is valid."
        break
    else
        echo "Email address $email is invalid."
    fi
done
```

which I also modified to accept lower case characters.

So why did the initial version you have not work?  For starters, you aren't actually executing the command you want.  The command would be parsed with the `=` assignment happening first, like you're assigning a local shell variable for the rest of the command to execute.  So in this case you're assigning `[` to `email_status`, then trying to execute `"$email" =~ ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$ ]` which isn't a real command.

Even if it were, your assignment still wouldn't work, because what you would actually have been wanting (aside from using `[[` so you can use the regex syntax) is to do that test, then store the exit code in `exit_status` like:

```
[[ "$email" =~ ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$ ]]
email_status=$?
```

and then make sure you update email_status within your loop, which your initial version did not do.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I cant vote you up because I did not reach the 15 points, I will do when i get there !!! thank

Comment: Slightly cleaner regex [[ $email =~ ^[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@[[:alnum:].-]+\.[[:alpha:].]{2,4}$ ]]